# Deserialize JSON Body self in C# Webinvoke function in Webserver

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization

I have a Webserver in C#. It works fine with my defined structures.

```
[DataContract]
  public class Action
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest , RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "CdnVaultSAPSyncServiceVar")]
    public string CreateJobVar(Action action)
    {
      return action.Name;
    }
```

But if i want to deserialise the body self, i got no body:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest , RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "CdnVaultSAPSyncServiceVar")]
    public string CreateJobVar(string action)
    {
      var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(action);
      return action.ToString();
    }
```

The String action is always "null".

I tried a lot also in the App.config file. But nothing helps. Are there any samples that do what I want? There is no problem if i have to derserialize all my function parameters in my server.

in app.config i tried this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="XxxBehaviour" name="My.WebService.Service">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/MyService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapableForHttps" contract="My.WebService.IService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="XxxBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <binding name="RawReceiveCapableForHttps">
        <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="My.WebService.RawContentTypeMapper, My, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </binding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (don't use c# reserverd words as the property names)

```
public string CreateJobVar(JToken jToken)
    {
     string name=jToken["Name"].ToString();
      return jToken.ToString();
    }
```

if it doesn't  work, json is not valid

if you want to send a string , your json body should be

```
"{ \"Name\":\"POWERSHELL.DoNothing.ps1\", \"Type\":\"ECMMAS\"}"
```

you  will need to serialize twice

```
var a = new Action {Name="POWERSHELL.DoNothing.ps1", Type="ECMMAS"};

var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that does not work. The variable "jsonString" is always "null". Like the variable "action" was in my description

Comment: @CPipe You posted the wrong question. You have to create a new post to ask why your "action" string is always null. But if you don't post the code that cals CreateJobVar nobody can help you.

Comment: Sorry I asked the wrong question. You are right. My problem is that action is always "null". I call my Webservice via Insonmia: It`s a Post-call  with URL http://localhost:8080/MyService/CreateJobVar and JSON Body like {
  "Name":"POWERSHELL.DoNothing.ps1",
  "Type":"ECMMAS"
}

Comment: Thanks for the hint with JToken. But if I use this type as variable in IClass and Class my servide won't start any longer. The Errormessage in the Events is:The service cannot be started. System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken" is a recursive collection data contract that is not supported. Change the definition of collection "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken" to remove references to itself.